# Wittgenstein's response to Russell's paradox

Tags: logic, paradoxes

Can someone explain Wittgenstein's response to Russell's paradox in the Tractatus? Is it possible to cast the response as a mathematical proof? All explanations I have found so far mix logical and philosophical terms, so I am uncertain what is actually being expressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

W's *Tractatus* is not a mathematical work.

Having said that, the *Tractatus* relies heavily on the logic of [Principia Mathematica](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/principia-mathematica/) and the [Theory of types](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/type-theory/#1).

In a nutshell, W's approach is [[see 3.333](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Tractatus_Logico-Philosophicus/3)] :

> A function cannot be its own argument, because the functional sign already contains the prototype of its own argument and it cannot contain itself.
>
> If, for example, we suppose that the function $F(fx)$ could be its own argument, then there would be a proposition “$F(F(fx))$”, and in this the outer function $F$ and the inner function $F$ must have different meanings; for the inner has the form $ϕ(fx)$, the outer the form $ψ(ϕ(fx))$. Common to both functions is only the letter “$F$”, which by itself signifies nothing.

This means that [Russell's paradox](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/russell-paradox/#TP), amounting at : $R(R) \text { iff } \lnot R(R)$ is a violation of the syntactical rules of the formalized language, because the rules prohibit that a function of "level" $n$ can be an argument of a function of the same "level".

See also 3.332 :

> No proposition can say anything about itself, because the propositional sign cannot be contained in itself (that is the “whole theory of types”).

Comment: Thank you for your response! Is it is possible to express this violation in a type theoretic formal language?

Comment: @nobody - see [Type Theory : Simple Type Theory and the λ-Calculus](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/type-theory/#1) : "The term $λx. ¬(x x)$
represents the predicate of predicates that do not apply to themselves. This term does not have a type however, that is, it is not possible to find $A$ such that $λx. ¬(x x) : (A→o) → o$ which is the formal expression of the fact that Russell's paradox cannot be expressed. "